# Cocos2dx iOS project with LUA

Tags: ios, xcode, lua, cocos2d-x

When I run Cocos2d-x iOS project in Xcode, it displays black screen in simulator.

Here is console log:
[image]

First time running Lua project, please help me to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed problem.

This is happened in cocos2d-x-3.17.2, in this extern.lua missing in below path

```
cocos2d-x-3.17.2/cocos/scripting/lua-bindings/script/cocos2d/extern.lua
```

Now I took same file from cocos2d-x-3.3 and its working now. Cheers